# Beginner―Texmaker: generate HTML, MathML

Tags: texmaker, html, mathml

I am very new to LaTeX and everything connected to it,but since I come from the HTML, I know what it means to use a markup language.

I try to setup Texmaker that I can generate MathML and or HTML files, on the Homepage of Texmaker there is an image that shows a kind of wizard for this, but I cannot find it.

I am working on ubuntu linux 12.04, I have `texlive-full` installed and

I am searching for help to find the »export« button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 repositories have an old version of `TeXmaker`.

So download the latest version of [Ubuntu 12.04 `deb` package from `TeXmaker` website](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html) based on 32 bit (i386) or 64 bit(amd64)

carry out the installation using [gdebi package installer](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingSoftware#Using_GDebi_to_install_packages),then you will find the under Tools menu-->`export via TeX4ht`